# In non-spatial contexts, when should I use "this" versus "that"?

Tags: pronouns, this-that

I'm always quite confused to choose which word should I put in the sentence like this/that :)

1. That/This is not a problem at all.
2. To be or not to be, this/that is the question.

I know which one I should choose in terms of positioning. But still I don't have that/this feeling for not an object.

Comment: Related to various degrees: [Using “that” and “this” interchangeably](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/using-that-and-this-interchangeably), [Should “that” or “it” be used in this sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18728/should-that-or-it-be-used-in-this-sentence), [Do “that” and “it” refer to different things in this sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20403/do-that-and-it-refer-to-different-things-in-this-sentence)

Comment: Consider languages that have 3 distance levels where English has 2, this and that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically, "that" was much more common for non-physical referents, except where it was cataphoric, i.e. referred to something which hadn't yet been clarified. So

> To be or not to be? That is the question

but

> This is the question: to be or not to be.

"This" would be used to emphasise the immediacy of the referent, or where there were two things being distinguished:

> I saw somebody rummaging in a rubbish bin. That appalled me.

but

> I saw several people smoking, and one person rummaging in a rubbish bin. This appalled me.

("This" is possible in the first case, and in my judgment brings the activity more to the fore).

I think there has been a trend in the last fifty years to use "this" more often than before, particularly in an academic (or academic-sounding) register. So "This is what we find" as opposed to the more informal "That's what we find".