# In this sb's case

Tags: grammaticality

I've got a question about English grammar. as I'm not a native English speaker, I have to make some sentences by myself.

Imagine a person has several problems, or cases, and now we are talking about a specific matter. In part of one of my sentences, I've said:

> In this Sb's case...

(I was pointing at a particular case)

The most important part of my question is that:

Is it grammatical wrong? Regardless of whether a native would use it or not...

I'll really appreciate your answers.

Comment: What does 'Sb' mean here?

Comment: @Spagirl - Somebody?

Comment: thank you for responding me back. but sth which I can't understand yet is that do your explanations indicate my phrase being wrong grammatically?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *Sb* means somebody, and that somebody has lots of problems, but you wish to talk about *just one of those problems*, then you would say:

> In this [particular] case

or

> In that [particular] case

#### Notes

1. You would use *particular*, if you wished to emphasise which of the problems you are referring to.
2. You don't need to refer to the person's name<sup>1</sup>.
3. This or that - stylistic choice<sup>2</sup>. See ["In that case" vs "in this case"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43110/in-that-case-vs-in-this-case)

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless there are a group of people, let's say: John; Fred, and; Pete - and they all have a problem (just one problem for each person, for this example), and you wish to talk about Fred's problem only, *then* you would say:

> In Fred's case

<sup>2</sup> *this* if you can point to it, *that* if it is a metaphorical idea, that you can't physically point at.